Full calendar custom header toolbar
I'm using a calendar component with the following headerToolbar configuration in my React application:
headerToolbar={{
  start: "TODAY prev,next",
  center: "TITLE",
  end: "DAYGRIDMONTH,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
}}

I want to display the words "today", "week", "day", and "month" in uppercase, but simply changing them to uppercase in the configuration isn't working. How can I achieve this formatting in the headerToolbar of my calendar component?

The values you put into the header toolbar are view names, not verbal descriptions. They are specific, and case-sensitive. Think of them more like IDs which tell fullCalendar uses to know which view to load, rather than what appears to the user. If you notice, in most cases the string you use here doesn't match what appears on the screen (especially if you are in a non-English locale!).
There is no direct way to change the description of the default views or buttons. What you can do though is create custom views and/or custom buttons whose settings largely match the default views, except for the text description.
If you want to make the title appear in uppercase, you should look at the title format option and the date formatting documentation. This is likely to require the use of an additional plugin to enable completely custom date formatting.
Example of use of custom views and buttons (this is using native JS syntax as I'm not a React user, but you can easily adapt it):
headerToolbar: {
  start: "todayBtnUC prev,next",
  center: "title",
  end: "dayGridMonthUC,timeGridWeekUC,timeGridDayUC"
},
views: {
  dayGridMonthUC: {
    type:"dayGridMonth",
    buttonText: "MONTH"
  },
  timeGridWeekUC: {
    type:"timeGridWeek",
    buttonText: "WEEK"
  },
  timeGridDayUC: {
    type:"timeGridDay",
    buttonText: "DAY"
  }
},
customButtons:
{
  todayBtnUC: {
    text: "TODAY",
    click: function() {
      calendar.gotoDate(new Date());
    }
  }
},
initialView: "dayGridMonthUC",

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoroLaa

P.S. Just as an aside: unless you are aiming for a very particular visual style overall, the use of all-capitals on the internet is usually considered the equivalent of shouting (instead of speaking normally). I would suggest thinking carefully about where, when and why you use that in your pages.
